# Link ID to same User

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

Hello I am using SQL SERVER 2008R2 and have tables which produces following output,

```
**Usertable**
USERID  Name LINKID
  1     abc    NULL
  2     pqr    NULL
  3     str    NULL
  4     xyz    NULL

**PhoneTable**
USERID  PhoneNumber
  1     123
  2     123
  3     12345
  4     34567

**EmailTable**
USERID  EmailID 
  1     abc@gmail.com
  2     pqr@gmail.com
  3     abc@gmail.com
  4     xyz@gmail.com
```

My requiremnet is, if records in **PhoneTable** have same `PhoneNumber` then same `LINKID` should be updated for both `USERID` in **USERTABLE**.

And if Users has same `EmailID` in **EmailTable**, Then same `LINKID` should be updated for both `USERID` in **USERTABLE**

My expected output for UserTable is,

```
 USERID  Name LINKID
  1     abc    1
  2     pqr    1
  3     str    1
  4     xyz    NULL
```

Userid 4 don't have same phonenNumber or EmailID, so it should stay Null.
Suggest me the Query or Procedure to get me the result. Thank you.

Comment: @Option : See the tags added.

Comment: could do this with merge and the output clause?

Comment: But from where LINKID 1 is coming in both the cases?

Comment: @ShakeerMirza, generate it with a Newid() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
First you get user id for same phone number and email id with help of CTE   
and update usertable based on CTE.

CREATE TABLE #Usertable(USERID INT,  Name VARCHAR(100), LINKID INT)
CREATE TABLE #PhoneTable(USERID INT,  PH VARCHAR(100))
CREATE TABLE #EmailTable(USERID INT,  Email VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO #Usertable (USERID ,  Name , LINKID )
SELECT   1,'abc',NULL UNION ALL 
SELECT   2,'pqr',NULL UNION ALL 
SELECT   3,'str',NULL UNION ALL 
SELECT   4,'xyz',NULL

INSERT INTO #PhoneTable (USERID ,  PH )
SELECT 1,'123' UNION ALL 
SELECT 2,'123' UNION ALL 
SELECT 3,'12345' UNION ALL 
SELECT 4,'34567'

INSERT INTO #EmailTable (USERID ,  Email) 
SELECT 1,'abc@gmail.com' UNION ALL 
SELECT 2,'pqr@gmail.com' UNION ALL 
SELECT 3,'abc@gmail.com' UNION ALL 
SELECT 4,'xyz@gmail.com'


;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT userid FROM #PhoneTable P1 WHERE 
  EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM #PhoneTable P2 WHERE P1.PH = P2.PH AND P1.USERID <>     
  P2.USERID)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT userid FROM #EmailTable P1 WHERE 
  EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM #EmailTable P2 WHERE P1.Email = P2.Email AND     
  P1.USERID <> P2.USERID)
)

UPDATE #Usertable SET LINKID = A.userid
FROM 
(
  SELECT MIN(userid) userid
  FROM CTE
) A
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM CTE B WHERE B.userid = #Usertable.USERID) 

**FOR UNIQUE LINKID**

UPDATE #Usertable SET LINKID = NEWID()
FROM CTE B WHERE B.userid = #Usertable.USERID

SELECT  * FROM #Usertable
```

Comment: 1 was just example, your query looks fine for me, but I need a unique ID for LINKEDID to be generated for same Phonenumbers or Emailid using NEWID() function.

Comment: Now its getting different LinkedId's for each user, I need same Id for matching users

Comment: After I declared variable for newid(),its working for me, thank you Mansoor.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
update usertable u
set linkid = (select min(userid) from 
                 (select userid from phonetable p
                  where p.phonenumber = (select phonenumber 
                                     from phonetable p1
                                     where p1.userid = u.userid)
                  union all
                  select userid from emailtable e
                  where e.emailid = (select emailid 
                                     from emailtable e1
                                     where e1.userid = u.userid)
                  )
              );
```

Answer (score 0):

Build Schema for the above case

```
CREATE TABLE #USER (USERID INT, NAME VARCHAR(20), LINKID INT)

INSERT INTO #USER
SELECT 1 AS USERID, 'abc' AS NAME, NULL AS LINKID
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 , 'pqr' , NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 , 'str', NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 4 , 'xyz', NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 5 , 'jkl', NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 6 , 'mno', NULL


CREATE TABLE #PhoneTable (USERID INT, PhoneNumber VARCHAR(20) )

INSERT INTO #PhoneTable
SELECT 1 AS USERID, '123' PhoneNumber
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS USERID, '123'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS USERID, '12345'
UNION ALL
SELECT 4 AS USERID, '34567'
UNION ALL
SELECT 5 AS USERID, '15233'
UNION ALL
SELECT 6 AS USERID, '15233'

CREATE TABLE #EmailTable (USERID INT, EmailID VARCHAR(50) )

INSERT INTO #EmailTable
SELECT 1 AS USERID, 'abc@gmail.com' EmailID
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS USERID, 'pqr@gmail.com'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS USERID, 'abc@gmail.com'
UNION ALL
SELECT 4 AS USERID, 'xyz@gmail.com'
```

Now update them individually like

```
--updating with Checking #PhoneTable
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT PhoneNumber
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1))+(SELECT ISNULL(MAX(LINKID),0) FROM #USER) LINKID 
FROM #PhoneTable 
GROUP BY PhoneNumber HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT USERID)>1
)
UPDATE U SET U.LINKID = C.LINKID FROM #USER U 
INNER JOIN #PhoneTable P ON U.USERID = P.USERID
INNER JOIN CTE C ON P.PhoneNumber = C.PhoneNumber

--updating with Checking #EmailTable
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT EmailID
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1))+(SELECT ISNULL(MAX(LINKID),0) FROM #USER) LINKID 
FROM #EmailTable 
GROUP BY EmailID HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT USERID)>1
)
UPDATE U SET U.LINKID = C.LINKID FROM #USER U 
INNER JOIN #EmailTable E ON U.USERID = E.USERID
INNER JOIN CTE C ON E.EmailID = C.EmailID
```

For Unique LINKID generation I have taken `ISNULL(MAX(LINKID),0)` and added it to `ROW_NUMBER`